# How to break a loop from within a getOrElse block?

Tags: loops, kotlin, exception

How would I break my infinite loop in the code below? When I try to simply use "break", I get the warning "break or continue jumps across a function or a class boundary".

```
while (true)
    runCatching {
        // do some stuff
    }.getOrElse {
        when (it) {
            is InterruptedException -> {
                // do some stuff
                TODO: FIGURE OUT HOW TO BREAK OUT OF WHILE LOOP
            }
            else -> {
                // do some other stuff
            }
    }.also {
        // do some stuff
    }
```

Comment: This is not the intended use for `runCatching`. It would be much clearer code to use try/catch in this particular situation. You can read about intended use cases here: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/result.md

Comment: This was implemented as a runCatching in order to have the else block for catching. When I implement as a try/catch and have a catch(e: Exception), that fails a detekt check for having too generic of an exception caught

Comment: Sounds like maybe Detekt needs to be configured differently if you’re having to hack around its intent. Whoever imposed that rule if they feel it is appropriate probably wouldn’t be happy with the workaround because it means the code robustness problem they were trying to fix is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You can label loops by naming them followed by an @ symbol `nameOfLoop@ while(true)` and then specify the label when you break by adding @ and the label `break@nameOfLoop;`